# How to get length of array in a i18n-file in JavaScript/angularJS?

Tags: javascript, json, internationalization

My translation file looks like this:

```
{
    "RANDOM": [
      {
        "ITEM": "basdf"
      },
      {
        "ITEM": "casdf"
      },
      {
        "ITEM": "dasdf"
      },
      {
        "ITEM": "easdf"
      }
    ]

}
```

I want to randomly display one of the items:

```
getQuestion() {
  const sizeOfRandomItems = 4;
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * sizeOfRandomItems);
  return this.$filter('i18n')('RANDOM.' + randomNumber + '.ITEM');
}
```

But whenever I wanted to add a new item in my translation file, I'd also have to manually update `sizeOfRandomItems`. Is there a way to get the size of the `RANDOM` array in the translation file?

I alread tried:

```
const arraySize = this.$filter('i18n')('RANDOM'); 
console.log(arraySize.length);
```

But first I get a warning:

```
i18n-translate.js:205 Missing key:
```

it returns `6` (which is the number of charachters in the key that holds the array `RANDOM`)

Comment: If you have a variable that contains your structure, then you can just do `myVariable.RANDOM.length`

Comment: @James At first I thought that it was that easy too, but it's not.

Answer (score -1):

if you are willing to use some library, you could load the json using Jquery. 
Parse it into an array and get the array length. Of cours this solutions will be heavy if you have alot of key, so i suggest you keep the result into a variable somewhere.

```js
var length;
function getQuestion() {
  const sizeOfRandomItems = 4;
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (length ? length : getJsonLength()));
  return this.$filter('i18n')('RANDOM.' + randomNumber + '.ITEM');
}

function getJsonLength() {
  $.getJSON("i18n.json", function(json) {
    var array = JSON.parse(json)
    length = array.length;
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

simplest might be to have an additional item in your translation file giving the current array length - so you could first read that information from translation and use that.

```
getQuestion() {
  const sizeOfRandomItems = parseINT(this.$filter('i18n')('RANDOM.LENGTH'), 10);
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * sizeOfRandomItems);
  return this.$filter('i18n')('RANDOM.' + randomNumber + '.ITEM');
}
```

simpler would be if you could load the object from translation file like eg. possible in i18next (https://www.i18next.com/objects-and-arrays.html) - not sure if that is possible in i18n library you use.